# RESTful WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, service

I am new to WCF Services.
We are creating a REST WCF Service which will be deployed on our IIS Server.
our client is a iPHone App which is going send data to our WCF Service.
In our Service I need to create a method will save data to 5 tables in  Database.
If its one or two fields they can simply pass string data but.
They need to pass atleast 10 fields .
I am wondering how the iPhone app will send the data to our application.
Any insight regarding how generally data will transmitted from Mobile Apps to WCF Service.
I really appreciate your help and if possible please give some example.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to transmit data to and from your IPhone in JSON-format since it's much more lightweight than SOAP for example. Also, JSON is perfectly supported by WCF 4.0 out of the box. For the IPhone, you can use SbJSON or TouchJSon for serializing/deserializing your data.

Comment: Hi Sander, Thanks for your answer. What are the other options we have other than JSOS. I heard JSON is meant for Client Side usage which are generally used in AJAX functionality . Can we use JSON on Server Side also. One more thing its not just iPhone App, it should be supported by iPhone, Andorid, Windows phone7.

Comment: If your client application should target multiple (mobile)platforms, I really recommend you to check first if you can workaround the development of mobile apps for every platform; have you considered using jQuery Mobile (http://jquerymobile.com)? In spite of the fact it is web-based, it provides the same user experience as an App. JSON is recommended since it's lightweight and therefore suitable for mobile devices (limited bandwidth, RAM, and so on). Another advantage is the fact that .NET perfectly understands JSON.